# Are There Normal RB3 Guitars

Tags: rock-band-3

Our guitars are beat to snot and we need new ones. We were holding off on buying new controllers until RB3 hit, assuming there would be a new line of MadKats (MatCats?) regular guitar (non-Pro Mode) controllers out.

I am not seeing any on line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha! Yes. Finally found one on line--I have looked for the last week or with no luck.

[http://www.amazon.com/Rock-Band-Wireless-Fender-Stratocaster-Controller/dp/B0040J1RIQ/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1288099376&sr=8-15](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040J1RIQ)

As a note I bought a RB3 5 button guitar controller yesterday at GameStop despite the website showing they didn't have the stock.

Comment: I actually was not at all aware. Good note for the both of us, I imagine. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, 16 more hours before I can.